# ESLint - Make PropTypes mandatory

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

Is there a way to add a rule into eslintrc where by every .js or .jsx file in a src folder must contain proptypes and/or defaultprops, and if it doesnt, an error is thrown.

Comment: eslint-plugin-react comes with some helpful options for validation of prop-types. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/tree/master/docs/rules

Or are you looking for something that explicitly checks if Component.propTypes = {} is set?

Answer (score 6):

In your .eslintrc file you need to add the following lines:

```
  plugins: [
      'react',
  ],
  rules: {
      'react/prop-types': ['error'],
  }
```